# GCC claims a friend function to be overloaded, ambiguous call, clang compiles

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

```
template <typename T>
class rp {
};

template <template <typename> class P>
struct b {
    template <class, template <typename> class FriendP>
    friend void f(b<FriendP> from);
};

template <class, template <typename> class P>
void f(b<P> from) {
}

int main() {
    b<rp> v;
    f<int>(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Clang 3.3 (svn) compiles fine, while GCC 4.8 rejects it:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:17:10: error: call of overloaded 'f(b<rp>&)' is ambiguous
  f<int>(v);
          ^
main.cpp:17:10: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:12:6: note: void f(b<P>) [with <template-parameter-1-1> = int; P = rp]
 void f(b<P> from) {
      ^
main.cpp:8:17: note: void f(b<FriendP>) [with <template-parameter-2-1> = int; FriendP = rp; P = rp]
     friend void f(b<FriendP> from);
                 ^
```

I wonder why GCC claims `f` to be overloaded. So I guess it's a GCC bug.

Which compiler is right?

Comment: Which `f()` does clang invoke?

Comment: Since only the `f` outside `b` definition has a body and there are no linker errors, that `f` has to be invoked. In fact there is only one `f`.

Comment: I'd say this is a GCC bug.

Comment: The only thing I see is `b<rp> v;`. Why does "templated" (the term of mine))) `rp` not parameterized?

Comment: the `friend f` inside `struct b` injects a non-template function into the surrounding (global) scope, but then the call with the explicit template parameter `f<int>` might throw gcc off the track. Just guessing without any compiler debugger.

Comment: all gcc versions on LiveWorkspace fail to compile this, but Clang 3.2 and Intel 13.01 work. My money is on a gcc bug.

Comment: @TemplateRex: I don't believe in this case the friend declaration declares a non-template function, since the friend declaration is itself a template declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Friend injection does no longer exist in the c++ standard, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick) for informations about this. However, since the friend function declared inside struct b "acts" on a parameter of type "b", the function is found via ADL (argument-dependant lookup). When this happens 2 different functions having the same signature are declared, and the compiler complains.

This is probably what you meant:

```
template <template <typename> class P>
struct b {
    template <class, template <typename> class FriendP>
    friend void f(b<FriendP> from){};
};
```

but don't use this in real code as it is, since "duplicate function" problems can, as you see, easily arise (proper use of namespaces can be of help with this respect).

The code can be tested [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=24844806b98f3a0aa2a2be755bade6be-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

A good reference for the use (as well as a good real-life example of why they are needed) of template friend functions can be found in item 46 of Effective c++

Comment: Why gcc thinks the friend function has 3 template parameters?

Comment: Because there actually are 3: the first one is the one identified by class, the second one is FriendP, the third one is the template argument of FriendP

Comment: The issue isn't visibility.  The issue is that both declarations of `f` should be seen as declaring the same function template.

Comment: @aschepler we didn't talk about visibility. Can you be more specific on the comment? Why do you say: "should be seen as...", you won't find anything like this in the standard!

Comment: 3.5/9 describes when two names "denote the same variable, function, type, enumerator, template or namespace", and these two `f` satisfy all the requirements.  14.5.6.1 is also relevant.

Comment: @StefanoFalasca: That's the problem. Why the first one is considered? Can't a class template have a friend which is not a template itself, or a template with a totally unrelated set of parameters?